# DataStage Column Generator Stage not working working properly

Tags: database, sorting, datastage

I need to add a column with a progressive number to a table with two columns: ID and Amount. The resulting table should be like this:

| ID | Amount | Progressive n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10000.00 | 1 |
| 21 | 9.67 | 1 |
| 21 | 11.27 | 2 |
| 21 | 9.46 | 3 |
| 21 | 12.27 | 4 |
| 21 | 90780.51 | 5 |
| 21 | 200.00 | 6 |
| 21 | 20.18 | 7 |
| 21 | 1045.04 | 8 |
| 21 | 3477.98 | 9 |
| 21 | 454390.00 | 10 |
| 21 | 24.50 | 11 |
| 21 | 54.76 | 12 |
| 21 | 12000.00 | 13 |
| 5 | 5.99 | 1 |
| 45 | 160000.00 | 1 |
| 45 | 29.00 | 2 |
| 45 | 1.98 | 3 |
| 45 | 2.56 | 4 |
| 56 | 659034.90 | 1 |
| 56 | 12000000.00 | 2 |
| 56 | 4781.35 | 3 |
| 56 | 1065.05 | 4 |
| 56 | 29.50 | 5 |
| 56 | 92000.00 | 6 |
| 56 | 10.00 | 7 |
| 56 | 4.35 | 8 |
| 56 | 52000000.00 | 9 |
| 56 | 8763.57 | 10 |
| 56 | 3065.05 | 11 |

But I get the wrong output. Something like this:

| ID | Amount | Progressive n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10000.00 | 1 |
| 21 | 9.67 | 1 |
| 21 | 11.27 | 2 |
| 21 | 9.46 | 3 |
| 21 | 12.27 | 4 |
| 21 | 90780.51 | 5 |
| 21 | 200.00 | 6 |
| 21 | 20.18 | 7 |
| 21 | 1045.04 | 8 |
| 21 | 3477.98 | 9 |
| 21 | 454390.00 | 10 |
| 21 | 24.50 | 11 |
| 21 | 54.76 | 12 |
| 21 | 12000.00 | 13 |
| 5 | 5.99 | 1 |
| 45 | 160000.00 | 1 |
| 45 | 29.00 | 2 |
| 45 | 1.98 | 3 |
| 45 | 2.56 | 4 |
| 56 | 659034.90 | 5 |
| 56 | 12000000.00 | 6 |
| 56 | 4781.35 | 7 |
| 56 | 1065.05 | 8 |
| 56 | 29.50 | 9 |
| 56 | 92000.00 | 10 |
| 56 | 10.00 | 11 |
| 56 | 4.35 | 12 |
| 56 | 52000000.00 | 13 |
| 56 | 8763.57 | 14 |
| 56 | 3065.05 | 15 |

When ID = 56, the progressive number starts with 5, instead of 1.

I tried to add a Sort Stage, ordering the table by ID, but I get almost the same error. It changes the order of the ID column, but it still assign the wrong number

| ID | Amount | Progressive n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 5.99 | 1 |
| 10 | 10000.00 | 1 |
| 21 | 9.67 | 2 |
| 21 | 11.27 | 3 |
| 21 | 9.46 | 4 |
| 21 | 12.27 | 5 |
| 21 | 90780.51 | 6 |
| 21 | 200.00 | 7 |
| 21 | 20.18 | 8 |
| 21 | 1045.04 | 9 |
| 21 | 3477.98 | 10 |
| 21 | 454390.00 | 11 |
| 21 | 24.50 | 12 |
| 21 | 54.76 | 13 |
| 21 | 12000.00 | 14 |
| 45 | 160000.00 | 1 |
| 45 | 29.00 | 2 |
| 45 | 1.98 | 3 |
| 45 | 2.56 | 4 |
| 56 | 659034.90 | 1 |
| 56 | 12000000.00 | 2 |
| 56 | 4781.35 | 3 |
| 56 | 1065.05 | 4 |
| 56 | 29.50 | 5 |
| 56 | 92000.00 | 6 |
| 56 | 10.00 | 7 |
| 56 | 4.35 | 8 |
| 56 | 52000000.00 | 9 |
| 56 | 8763.57 | 10 |
| 56 | 3065.05 | 11 |

When ID = 21, the progressive number starts with 2, instead of 1.

I also tried to add the Amount column to the ordering in the Sort Stage, but it just changes the row where the error appears.

It seems to me that the Column Generator Stage gets the partition wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

Just ask if any more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

To add a column, I would suggest to use a `Transform Stage` instead of a <strike>`Column Generator Stage`</strike>.

You can use `stage variables` within the Transformer to generate the values. For simplification, set the transform stage (or the entire job) to run in sequential mode.

The data on the input link needs to be sorted.

If you need to run in parallel, you *could* use `@PARTITIONNUM`, `@NUMPARTITIONS` and `@INROWNUM` to deal with partitioned processing, but the following should also work in parallel without that, as long as the input link is partitioned on the ID column (only) and of course also sorted.

#### Example

Add a sort stage followed by a transform stage to your job. in the sort stage, partition and sort the data by ID. Edit the transform stage like this:

##### Input Link

| DSLink2 |
| --- |
| ID |
| Amount |

##### Stage Variables

| Derivation | Stage Variable | Initial value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| svID | svPreviousID | (not needed) |
| DSLink2.ID | svID | -1 |
| If svID = svPreviousID Then svProgN +1 Else 1 | svProgN | (not needed) |

##### Output Link

| Derivation | Column Name |
| --- | --- |
| DSLink2.ID | ID |
| DSLink2.Amount | Amount |
| svProgN | ProgressiveN |

#### Process Explanation

First Row (`ID = 5`):

1. `svID` is `-1` (init. value), setting the `svPreviousID` to `-1`.
2. `DSLink2.ID` will set `svID` to `5`
3. The condition `svID = svPreviousID` is `false`, thus `svProgN` is set to `1`

Second Row (ID = 10):

1. `svID` *(from previous step)* sets `svPrevID` to `5`
2. `DSLink2.ID` sets `svID` to `10`
3. Condition is false, sets `svProgN` to `svProgN + 1` which is `2`

Third row (ID = 20):

1. `svPreviousID` := `svID` (`10`)
2. `svID` := `DSLink2.ID` (`20`)
3. (condition is false) `svProgN` := `1`

Fourth row (ID = 20):

1. `svPreviousID` := `svID` (`20`)
2. `svID` := `DSLink2.ID` (`20`)
3. (condition is true) `svProgN` := `svProgN + 1` ( which is `2`)

and so on...